# Fetching Data From Google Calendar API with C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I would like to fetch data from Google Calendar using Google Calendar API from a C# application.

I have my users' emails and password so I don't need OAuth or something and I'm following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs).

Here's a sample code:

```
FeedQuery query = new FeedQuery();
Service service = new Service("cal","company-app-v1.0");
service.setUserCredentials("fname.lname@gmail.com", "passphrase");
query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/fname.lname@gmail.com/private/full");
AtomFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
System.Console.WriteLine("Start-------------");
System.Console.WriteLine(calFeed.Entries.Count);
System.Console.WriteLine("Finish-------------");
```

What I don't understand is that do I have to specify the service name and application name in the Service constructor or in the Developers Console ??

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are refrenceing is from August 13, 2012  [.net client library](https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs).  It will not work with the current version of the [Google .net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) nor will it work with the current version of the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).

It is not possible to access Google Calendar using a Login and password you must use Open authentication as stated here: [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth)

> Every request your application sends to the Google Calendar API must
>   include an authorization token. The token also identifies your
>   application to Google.
>
> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other
>   authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses
>   Google+ Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.